# How do I print all characters included in an encoding in java

Tags: java

I need to have a list of characters my for my text editor I am building. Basically, I want a program to write the following for each character in UTF-32(and others, but separately) to a file:
[Character Name], [Character]
The name part is optional, but I at least want to have a full list without excess information that I can copy and paste from. I tried looking at other threads on stack overflow and other sources, and found somewhat similar questions, but none of them were what I needed. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a character set (Unicode) and an encoding (UTF-32/UTF-16/UCS-2/UTF-8)? [This](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) might be a good read while you're thinking about your editor.

Comment: As Kayaman commented, you are conflating a character set such as [Unicode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) with a [character encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) such as [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32). First educate yourself to separate the two concepts. After that, study the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) methods on classes `Character`, `String`, and `StringBuilder`. Do not use the `char` type. After all that, the solution is quite simple and obvious.

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thank you!